# Why is bias layer shape not equal to the weight layer shape in Custom Model which has custom layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

I stumped across a Custom dummy Linear Regression model where the code is like:

```
class RegressionModel(tf.keras.Model): # every new model has to use Model
    '''
    A Model that performs Linear Regression 
    '''
    def __init__(self,in_units,out_units):
        '''
        args:
            in_units: number of input neurons
            out_units: number of output units
        '''
        super(RegressionModel,self).__init__() # constructor of Parent class 
        
        self.in_units = in_units
        self.out_units = out_units
        
        self.w = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.GlorotNormal()((self.in_units,self.out_units))) 
        # make weight which has initial weights according to glorot_normal distribution
        
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(self.out_units)) # bias is mostly zeros
            
    
    def call(self,input_tensor):
        '''
        execurte forward pass
        args:
            input_tensor: input tensor which will be fed to the network
        '''
        return tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.w) + self.b
```

I want to ask why is `weight` has 2 D shape of `in,out` but bias has only `out` and more specifically why is `weight` of a 2D shape?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**

first is a matrix multiplication and than an addition.

input = 10 values
hidden_layer_1 = 7 values

w1 = [|input|, |hidden_layer_1|] -> [10, 7]
b1 = |hidden_layer_1| -> [7]

hidden_layer_1 = activation(input * w1 + b1)

Therefore it is correct.

**General**
That is a pretty basic question, you should start learning the theory before checking out implementation.

Start with some basic introductions that also cover linear algebra.
E.g. Andrew Ngs course on coursera.
Ian Goodfellows book is online for free, but no light lecture to start with:
https://www.deeplearningbook.org/